# DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper Could not decode json type

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka, my producer is `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.3.12` and consumer is `org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.1.7.RELEASE`
I am getting the following error on the consumer side

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#41-0-C-1 DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper Could not decode json type: abc-123 for key: myKey1 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'abc': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: (byte[])"abc-123"; line: 1, column: ]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:703)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3532)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2627)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:832)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:729)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4141)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4000)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3091)
at org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.lambda$toHeaders$1(DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.java:233)
at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.toHeaders(DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.java:216)
at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.toMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:106)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:229)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:75)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:51)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.lambda$onMessage$0(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:120)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:211)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:40)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1071)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1051)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:998)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:866)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:724)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My consumer code:

```
@KafkaListener(containerFactory = "ListenerContainerFactory", topics = "${kafka.topic}")
public void receive(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord, @Headers Map headers ) (

}
```

and the config is similar to this [ListenerConfig](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-kafka-adding-custom-header-kafka-message-example/)
including the method

```
@Bean
public DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper headerMapper(){
    return new DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper();
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to show the complete headers. It looks like the json-types header is mal-constructed.

Comment: @GaryRussell can you please clarify , what do u mean the complete headers ?

Comment: I need to see the actual contents of the record headers.

Comment: The header, key=myKey1 and value=abc-123

Comment: I need to see all the headers; specifically, this error can only occur if a badly-formed header named `spring_json_header_types` is present.